# Twilio unmuting a call

Tags: twilio

The code below mute a call in progress properly but does not unmute the call?

```
$.each(['mute','unmute'], function(index, value) { 
$('#button' + value).click(function(){ 
if(conn) {
if (value=='mute')
conn.mute(true)
if (value=='unmute')
conn.mute(false)
} 
});
});

<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" value="mute" id="buttonmute"></td>
<td></td>
<td><input type="button" value="unmute" id="buttonunmute"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this was solved by updating to their latest version. Somewhere on their site, I had gotten the url to their 1.1 script, but apparently the conn.mute(false) only works with 1.2:
//static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js